# Struggling with Android Layout

Tags: java, android

I am struggling in how to [**create this layout**](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/5599/androidlayout.png) *[ImageShack Link]* for my android application.

I tried nesting several things into each other but I kept getting errors and I finally have some code which does nothing like I want it to. I hope I get an idea on what layouts I should use and how I nest them together.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:text="94.6" android:id="@+id/id_number" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:text="KG" android:id="@+id/id_unit" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow03" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button android:text="@+id/Add" android:id="@+id/add_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

        <Button android:text="@+id/View" android:id="@+id/view_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `RelativeLayout` for the whole thing that includes another `RelativeLayout` for the upper part of the screen (Big Word here and the rest)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also go with RelativeLayout, maybe, if you're new on android dev and want to test your layouts on a wysiwyg ide, you can use droiddraw...

Answer (score 0):

pseudo xml:

```
<Vertical LinearLayout>

    <BigWord TextView align="center" />
    <Horizontal LinearLayout>
        <TextView 1 />
        <TextView 2 />
    <Horizontal LinearLayout>

</Vertical LinearLayout>

<TableLayout>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView NothingHere />
        <TextView TextHere />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button 1 />
        <Button 2 />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `TableLayout`. Check out this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can use TableLayout under ViewFlipper.. and use TableRow for all the texts & buttons, also use the attribute 'stretchColumns' in table layout, that will help you to add the number of columns you want..

and also you can take help from this site- 
http://www.knowledge-transfers.com/it/android-layout-tutorial/

this helps me a lot..